# minecraft wont load with thermal expansion installed but works with out thermal expansion and i have 54 mods the game says normaly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

hi the title is all i can say but ill try. ok so i clock play in the launcher for forge 1.7.10 it launches fine and fast without thermal expansion but when i install it it starts the launcher closes as usual and i have it set up (it = the launcher) to reopen when the game closes so i click play it loads (in launcher still) launcher closes about 10 seconds later reopen with no crash report there is just the normal tabs there although i am going to post the game output tab. here it is

```
[00:03:51] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[00:03:51] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Using primary tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[00:03:51] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[00:03:51] [main/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader version 7.99.26.1481 for Minecraft 1.7.10 loading
[00:03:51] [main/INFO] [FML]: Java is Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, version 1.8.0_91, running on Windows 10:x86:10.0, installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91
[00:03:51] [main/INFO] [FML]: [AppEng] Core Init
[00:03:51] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod codechicken.core.launch.CodeChickenCorePlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft
[00:03:52] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod cofh.asm.LoadingPlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft
[00:03:52] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod cofh.asm.LoadingPlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft
[00:03:52] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod codechicken.core.launch.DepLoader does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft
[00:03:52] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod ic2.core.coremod.IC2core does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft
[00:03:52] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod net.malisis.core.asm.MalisisCorePlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft
[00:03:52] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod mekanism.common.asm.LoadingHook does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft
[00:03:52] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod micdoodle8.mods.miccore.MicdoodlePlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft
[00:03:52] [main/INFO] [STDOUT]: [micdoodle8.mods.miccore.DepLoader$DepLoadInst:<init>:333]: MicdoodleCore searching for dependencies in mods file: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods
[00:03:52] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod codechicken.nei.asm.NEICorePlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft
[00:03:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[00:03:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
[00:03:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[00:03:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[00:03:52] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:53] [main/INFO] [FML]: Found valid fingerprint for Minecraft Forge. Certificate fingerprint e3c3d50c7c986df74c645c0ac54639741c90a557
[00:03:53] [main/INFO] [FML]: Found valid fingerprint for Minecraft. Certificate fingerprint cd99959656f753dc28d863b46769f7f8fbaefcfc
[00:03:53] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:53] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:53] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:53] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:53] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:53] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:53] [main/INFO] [IC2-core]: Loaded library EJML-core-0.26.jar.
[00:03:53] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:53] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:53] [main/INFO] [STDOUT]: [micdoodle8.mods.miccore.MicdoodlePlugin:getASMTransformerClass:102]: Successfully Registered Transformer
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [STDOUT]: [micdoodle8.mods.miccore.MicdoodlePlugin:injectData:295]: [Micdoodle8Core]: Patching game...
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [STDOUT]: [micdoodle8.mods.miccore.MicdoodlePlugin:injectData:295]: [Micdoodle8Core]: Patching game...
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [malisiscore]: [ChunkCollisionTransformer] Hook registered for net.minecraft.world.World
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [malisiscore]: [ChunkCollisionTransformer] Hook registered for net.minecraft.world.World
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [malisiscore]: [ChunkCollisionTransformer] Hook registered for net.minecraft.item.ItemBlock
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [malisiscore]: [ChunkCollisionTransformer] Hook registered for net.minecraft.network.NetHandlerPlayServer
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [malisiscore]: [ChunkBlockTransformer] Hook registered for net.minecraft.world.chunk.Chunk
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.TerminalTweaker
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.TerminalTweaker
[00:03:54] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Launching wrapped minecraft {net.minecraft.client.main.Main}
[00:03:55] [main/INFO] [STDOUT]: [micdoodle8.mods.miccore.MicdoodleTransformer:printLog:1989]: Galacticraft successfully injected bytecode into: sv (1 / 1)
[00:03:55] [main/INFO] [STDOUT]: [micdoodle8.mods.miccore.MicdoodleTransformer:printLog:1989]: Galacticraft successfully injected bytecode into: sa (1 / 1)
[00:03:55] [main/ERROR] [LaunchWrapper]: Unable to launch
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/entity/player/EntityPlayer
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:72) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:72) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/entity/EntityLivingBase
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:72) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:72) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/entity/Entity
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:72) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.entity.Entity
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:72) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file net/minecraft/entity/Entity
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:72) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 6 more
Exception in thread "main" [00:03:55] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:-1]: cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLSecurityManager$ExitTrappedException
[00:03:55] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:-1]:   at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLSecurityManager.checkPermission(FMLSecurityManager.java:25)
[00:03:55] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:-1]:   at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExit(Unknown Source)
[00:03:55] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:-1]:   at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Unknown Source)
[00:03:55] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:-1]:   at java.lang.System.exit(Unknown Source)
[00:03:55] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:-1]:   at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:138)
[00:03:55] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:-1]:   at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't help with technical issues involving mods, so I'm required to flag this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for modded Minecraft.  We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your FML is too old, try upgrading it from 7.99.26.1481 to 10.13.4.1558

http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.7.10.html